# Dojox/app keeping models synchronized with store

Tags: model-view-controller, dojo, dojox.mobile, dojox.app

I am currently using dojox/app to create a SPA, and I am starting now to add stores and models. I have been able to create a store from a json object, to create a model from the store, and to bind fields to the model using dojox mvc. However, I have something that I have not yet been able to do: update a 2nd model that is binded to the same store as the 1st one.

I will give an example. I have this store:

```
        win.global.modelApp = {}; 
        modelApp.names = {
            identifier: "id",
            items: [{
                "id": 1,
                "First": "John",
                "Last": "Doe",
            },{
                "id": 2,
                "First": "John2",
                "Last": "Doe",
            }]
        }
```

and then I create two models using this store in the config.json file:

```
"stores": {
    "namesStore":{
        "type": "dojo/store/Memory",
        "params": {
            "data": "modelApp.names"
        }
    }
},

"models": {
    "namesXUnused": {
        "modelLoader": "dojox/app/utils/mvcModel",
        "type": "dojox/mvc/EditStoreRefListController",
        "params":{
            "store": {"$ref":"#stores.namesStore"}
        }
    },
    "namesXUnused2": {
        "modelLoader": "dojox/app/utils/mvcModel",
        "type": "dojox/mvc/EditStoreRefListController",
        "params":{
            "store": {"$ref":"#stores.namesStore"}
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my HTML file, I have a field binded to `namesXUnused` (property `First`), and another binded to `namesXUnused2` (property `First`). When I edit the first field, I then have a button that commits these changes to the store. I can see via debugger that the store data has been correctly updated. However, I cannot get the second field to reflect the changes. Is there a way to refresh or recreate the model from the store?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set "observable": true, on the store to use an Observable store since you want to have updates to the store be reflected back to the models.  There are examples in the dojox/app/tests (and the dojox/mvc/tests) if you have problems, but just adding:
"observable": true, to your namesStore should do it.
"stores": {
    "namesStore":{
        "type": "dojo/store/Memory",
        "observable": true,
        "params": {
            "data": "modelApp.names"
        }
    }
},

Regards,
Ed

Comment: Hi Ed, tried your suggestion, but it still does not work as expected. The thing is, when I commit the first model, I see that if I execute again the `namesXUnused2.queryStore()`, I get the new results and I can bind the `observe` method. However, in the HTML, I have the bind in the following syntax: `<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at(this.loadedModels.namesXUnused2, 'model')">` and the problem is that this model property is not reflecting the changes. Any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Ed, I have apparently fixed the problem by getting the new query results after the commit (`this.view.loadedModels.namesXUnused.commit(); this.view.loadedModels.namesXUnused2.model = this.view.loadedModels.namesXUnused2.query();`). I will implement a notification mechanism to make sure a commit triggers all models binded to the same store to refresh their data. Thank you very much!